# Is it possible to edit a saved address on the checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

Is it possible to add an edit button to a saved address on the checkout page and edit it here without going to the my addresses page? Like the way Magento lets you edit the new address you created on the checkout.

I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check https://github.com/sohelrana09/checkout

Comment: Thanks! @SohelRana I'll check it out